# Publishing an API without any existing backend API for it

Tags: handler, wso2-api-manager

I linked some existing back-end APIs to the API Publisher. 
Due to some reasons, I need to create an API without any existing back-end API for it in a specific route (for example in .../myAPI/ path). The API should do something and then return a response to user. 
how can I do this using WSO2 API manager? Do I need to write a handler for it? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is it for testing purpose?

Comment: No, there is a legacy SSO and moving its users is not possible at this stage. I should create a login API. The API receives user-pass and validate it through the SSO and return the token received from the SSO.